# Failed to connect to installer service

Tags: backup, hyper-v, veeam

i have a problem with veeam backup and replication 9.
the problem is when i try to restore one of my virtual machines in a new location that it is on my back up server i get an error that
[Backup Server Name] Failed to connect to installer service.
can some one please help me on this case
my windows server is 2012 and my virtual machine is a hyper-v virtual machine.

Comment: I don‘t have the same problem but I know that there is a Known-Issue (mentioned by our Supporter). I can‘t explain the solution but here is a KB: https://www.veeam.com/kb2263

Comment: i checked version of DLL and service on the Host but there was no mismatch between them,and still couldn't solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

The step i did to solve this problem is as below:
1. I go to services.msc and restarted Veeam Installer Service.
2. In Veeam software at section backup infrastructure i rescanned all servers and i also set my credentials again.
at last i restarted server and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

i did not have an ip that has been set to my server, after i set it up, i restarted  veeam installer service and it worked. another point was that it had not created c:\backup automatically so i created it manually.